# I've got a problem with Vue data (components rendering problem)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm working on a VueJs project, i'm new in this world. I used to use NodeJs with ExpressJs before.

Here is my problem :

in the file "App.vue"

here is the JS, and HTML :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#mainComponents',
  data: {
    home: false,
    tower: false,
    faq: false,
    follow: false
  }
});
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="mainComponents" id="mainComponents">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active li"><a v-on:click.native="home = true, faq = false, tower = false, follow = false" class="home active">Acceuil</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a v-on:click.native="tower = true, faq = false, home = false, follow = false" class="tower">Tower Ascension</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a v-on:click.native="faq = true, tower = false, home = false, follow = false" class="faq">F.A.Q.</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a v-on:click.native="follow = true, faq = false, tower = false, home = false" class="follow">Nous suivre</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <img class="gradient" src="">
        <div id="typeContainer">
                <home v-if="home = true" id="home"/>
                <tower v-if="tower = true" id="tower"/>
                <div v-if="faq = true" id="faq"/>
                <div v-if="follow = true" id="follow"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to show the component "home", and then, after a click on the "Tower Ascension" nav element, I want to hide "home" and show component "tower". The problem is : The 2 components are show, on load, and the toggle don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `v-if` statements on your components, you are assigning `true` to `home` and then returning that, not comparing `home` to `true`. Comparison is done using `===`, not `=`.

```
    <div id="typeContainer">
            <home v-if="home === true" id="home"/>
            <tower v-if="tower === true" id="tower"/>
            <div v-if="faq === true" id="faq"/>
            <div v-if="follow === true" id="follow"/>
    </div>
```

However, you don't need to do a comparison at all because these are already boolean values:

```
    <div id="typeContainer">
            <home v-if="home" id="home"/>
            <tower v-if="tower" id="tower"/>
            <div v-if="faq" id="faq"/>
            <div v-if="follow" id="follow"/>
    </div>
```

And unless you want to show more than one component at once, it is probably easier to maintain a string that stores the name of the current page instead of maintaining 4 booleans.

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#mainComponents',
  data: {
    currentComponent: "home"
  }
});
```

**Vue:**

```
<div id="typeContainer">
        <home v-if="currentComponent === 'home'" id="home"/>
        <tower v-if="currentComponent === 'tower'" id="tower"/>
        <div v-if="currentComponent === 'faq'" id="faq"/>
        <div v-if="currentComponent === 'follow'" id="follow"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precisely answer. Your string idea is very good, I'll use it. I've got a last problem now. The v-on:click who normaly change 'currentComponent' do not work ...
Here is the way i'm using it : <html v-on:click="currentComponent = 'tower'"></html>

Comment: @Dimtri You can't place Vue event handlers on the `html` element. Vue will only affect HTML inside of the template element, the element whose selector is specified by `el`, which in this case is that `div` with id `mainComponents`.

Comment: Yes sorry, i used `html` as an example, but in my code, v-on:click are on `button` elements.